# How do I uniformly apply the same texture to many uneven faces on a mesh, such as a road?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm very new to blender and was following a tutorial to build roads. This worked out pretty well, and now I want to add a road texture to my road.

Here is an image of the mesh, it is basically just many semi-square faces on the same mesh.
[image]

I want to apply a road texture to at least the non-intersection road segments, as I understand these would require a different approach.

[image]

So far what I've tried is I've smart unwrapped the road and scaled the resulting UV map so that a single square fills the area, then used a road texture as input. This worked, but only for one direction. The white stripe in the middle of the road was not evenly aligned. I can also just manually work on the UV map or paint it, but with this many segments it's too much work to be feasible.

Below is kind of what I want (I've tried emulating it with paint), but I can't find out the Google terms that will help me solve this myself.
[image]

Is there any way to apply a road texture to each of these faces, so that the middle white stripe of the road is always centered and respected?

I've uploaded my Blender project here: https://easyupload.io/s3s0d5

Comment: Hello :). Since some road segments aren't perfectly straight, you could use the *UV > Follow Active Quads* option. If you share the mesh, I'll post a full answer with examples :).

Comment: @JachymMichal That would be wonderful. I've included a link to download the blender file.

Comment: add the texture pls to the blend file.

Comment: @Sanbaldo I don't know how to do that. I just used a random image I found on the internet. Any road texture will do, try this one: https://slm-assets.secondlife.com/assets/25046709/lightbox/road3.jpg?1574279825

Comment: @Zimano Thanks for the link. That will do it. Just for your info: In the image editor you can embed the selected image into the blend file with the menu command *Image > Pack* or *File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend*. There you can also unpack them again.

Comment: @Blunder good tip! Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the *Follow Active Quads* command.
It's fast and gives good results since none of your roads is perfectly straight.

1. Select the segment you want to unwrap
2. Go *UV > Follow Active Quads*
3. Scale and move the UV islands in the UV editor (they will all end up on top of each other)

<sup>Note: Sometimes the command doesn't work properly, so just reset the selected faces (*UV > Reset*) and try again</sup>

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I want, thanks! I'll wait 24h before accepting to see all the other ideas :)

Comment: No problem :) If you get stuck anywhere, let me know. Good luck with your project.

Comment: I tried it and it works out absolutely great, but takes a little work because if I understand correctly, I have to select each street separately, taking care not to pick intersections and such, then map it like you showed. Or am I misunderstanding the technique? Would it be possible to do all streets at once?

Comment: Yeah, you have to do it one by one, due to the intersections :).